# Error 502 Bad Gateway when starting tomcat on port 8080 OS X

Tags: tomcat

Cannot start tomcat on port 8080. The log message is "Address already in use".

The command lsof -i :8080 is returning

COMMAND     PID USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME

InfoSearc 24276 root   10u  IPv6 0x92ebb026e24857ef      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)

I kill it with "kill -9" command, but the error still happening.

How can I fix it?. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. sudo lsof -iTCP:8080 -sTCP:LISTEN 
   COMMAND     PID USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
   UpgradeSe 52647 root    9u  IPv6 0x21313707621edqfb      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)
2. sudo kill -9 PID
   get the PID from the step1

   > sudo kill -9 52647